# Salt and electricity

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, home-experiment

Recently, I did an experiment with salt and electric current. I set up an open electric current in a used battery holder where the missing part of the circuit is two metal plates. I then fill this open space with table salt. Then, I close the circuit by putting a 3V battery inside the battery holder. Judging by the rise in the circuit's temperature, I think there was a current flowing through the circuit. I then turn the whole battery holder upside down and the salt stayed there instead of falling down. Once I removed the battery, the salt fell down onto the table.
I repeated the experiment 3 times with the same result.

I don't know what is the force that was keeping the salt in place? Can somebody please help me.
Thank you. 
[image]

P/s: Sorry for my terrible drawing, it's my first time using a website to sketch a circuit (or anything).

Comment: Would you mind adding a sketch of the setup?

Comment: I suspect that your table salt isn't perfectly dry.

Comment: I suspected salt is not dry as well but what I don't understand is what force kept them from falling off from the circuit when electric current went through them.

Comment: Very interesting experiment. You should repeat it with dry salt (2 h @ 150 C). Moist salt conduct electricity, dry does not. +1 from me.

Comment: How big is the salt chamber?

Comment: It was not a chamber but rather a pile of salt between the two metal plates. This experiment was conducted in the case of a used clock so the size of the salt pile and circuit was quite small. The two small metal plates were about 5 mm apart.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like the electric field (perhaps added by the current flow) turned the salt crystals into electric dipoles, which were then attracted to each other and to the charged plates.

Comment: Can you be a bit more detail, please?

Comment: This might work with much higher voltages.